# Adding Dynamic Value to the fa fa-info-circle when user hovers on it

Tags: angular, font-awesome

In our project, we are deriving some total value and we need to show the break up when hovering on the fa fa-info-circle icon as below

Base Fare - 100
Reservation Charge - 50
Catering Charge - 20

---

Total Fare - 170

Currently we are showing only just Base Fare + Reservation Charge + Catering Charge and not the value as it is dynamic. user needs with the value as above

Any suggestion on the same is appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please share your implementation as well so that it could be identified as to what's missing.

Comment: more info a stackblitz will be appreciate

Comment: currently we are having a String Variable in which we are just providing the value as breakdown = "Base Fare + Reservation Charge + Catering Charge" and in the tooltip we have given the string {{breakdown}}

Comment: i will try to add the code in stackblitz. but i am using the String Variable and it is static to show the break up